# Is there a better way than using a switch statement to access different properties of a variable in swift?

Tags: swift, loops, properties

I have this code that uses a `for` loop to iterate through every pixel of an image and then based on a user choice changes the value of the red, green or blue channel.

I am using a `switch` statement to select the channel and the iterate through every pixel in a `for` loop for that pixels appropriate color property.  It feels very cludgy but I can't think of a way to simplify it.

Is there another way to access the property so I can eliminate the `switch` statement and just have one for loop that select the right pixel color based on user choice?

```
func applyFilterTo(image:UIImage,forColor:String, withIntensity:Int) -> RGBAImage {
  var myRGBA = RGBAImage(image:image)!
  switch forColor {
  case "RED":
    for x in 0..<myRGBA.width {
      for y in 0..<myRGBA.height {
        let pixelIndex = y * myRGBA.width  + x
        var pixel = myRGBA.pixels[pixelIndex]
        let newValue = Double(pixel.red) + (Double(withIntensity)/100)*Double(pixel.red)
        myRGBA.pixels[pixelIndex].red = UInt8(max(0,min(255,newValue)))
      }
    }
  ...
}
```

the above repeats for other options but the only thing that changes is the property I choose (red, blue, green).  Better way to do this?

Comment: you should check out CoreGraphics and CoreImage.

Comment: It depends what the other cases look like. If they are parallel, you may be able to express the parallelism more succinctly. For example, surely all the cases have to have the two `for` loops.  So why isn't the switch _inside_ the two `for` loops? Keep reasoning like that until all the parallelism is outside the switch and you've honed the cases to the minimal difference between them.

Comment: I had the switch inside the for loop to start but that ends up calling the switch statement for every pixel and it felt like extra processing that didn't seem to be needed although the alternative is this repeating code.  The other cases look just like this one except instead of pixel.red, I change pixel.green or pixel.blue.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is replacing switch statements with [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch), such as the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Depending on how many options you will have in the switch statement, the switch statement is the easiest to read and understand.